# iframe scrolling of a object

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position

I am working on a online (html/css/javascript)calculator of calories + nutrition needs. This calculator is just a couple of radio-buttons text inputs and selects.

You have to fill in / select / check things on the left half of calculator and the results are shown on the right. I have set the position of the right half to fixed, so when user fills the left side (which is much taller) and scrolls down, the right side stays at the top of display and he doesn't have to scroll all the way up to see the results.

This calculator has to be in a separate html file and it has to be displayed on the actual website via iframe. The thing is, that in my separate html file, the right side is fixed, and while scrolling it remains at the top, but on that site it is not working.

It is site that belongs to a friend of mine so I can not change that i-frame solution.

My question is: Is it possible to have that right side always on the top, while displaying the i frame on that site? I hope that you understand. If not, please ask and I will try to be more specific.

I don't know what kind of code should I add here but here is css of the right side of my calc:

```
 #contentRight {position:fixed; top:0px;}
```

and here is that iframe:

```
 <iframe src="http://..." height="800" width="690"   scrolling="no" id="iframeKalk" marginheight="0" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to go on. I made a fiddle that shows it works as expected ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/28MFL/) is the inner html page with the calculator, and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cspZb/1/) is the outer page containing the iframe), so there must be something amiss in the parts of the code that you're not showing.

Comment: Also, you say "I can not change that i-frame solution" but do you mean you can't change HTML/CSS/JS of the calculator page, or you can't change anything about the page containing the iframe?

Comment: I cannot change anything about the page containing the iframe. I can modify calculator

Comment: I can modify calculator but not the page. He also added this piece of code to my calculator: $('#iframeKalk',  window.parent.document).height(1200); so the calculator is fully visible on the page

Comment: Can you modify the jsfiddle (or create a new one) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I modified it a little. The thing is, that the iframe adjusting its height according to the height of the calculator (so there is no scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

I guess , i got it what you mean..
basically you are trying to make a calculator , with one side right allways on the top, while displaying the i-frame on the other side.

yes you can have taht..
you need to make two html pages for that..
say, 1. main.html
     2. frame.html

in main.html fill the content that you always want to display, as in your condition you want every thing on right side always so make two div tags ("right_stationary", "left-iframe")specifying the width of that your right panel which always will be showing.

now go to your left-iframe div tag and insert code like

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" style="position:fixed;margin-top:-31px;width:75%;height:91%" margin-left:0px;margin-right: 80px ;frameborder="0" src="frame.html" scrolling="yes" runat =server></iframe>
```

note: check the right margin according to your comfort, i mean how much you want.

i have made a sample with two html pages one is always stationart at the top and another is just rotating,(taking you from one site to another)

http://freebits.gq

hope it will help.